# Why does Excel 2013 round up result in a cell?

Tags: excel

```
I Create a new Excel 2013 file
I select the three first cells in column A
I select format cell
I choose Number
I check Use thousand separator
I choose 0 decimal
I enter in A1 the number 961748947
I enter in A2 the number 961748941
I enter in A3 = A1 * A2

Excel displays in A3 the value of 924 961 031 285 115 000
instead of                        924 961 031 285 115 127
```

Why does Excel 2013 round up the value ?
How to get the exact result ?

Comment: Excel only has precision to 15 digits.  Your number is larger than 15 digits, so Excel can only properly calculate the first 15 digits.  If you are working with numbers that large, you'll probably need a different program or calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tigeravatar said, Excel only has precision up to 15 digits.  But from this [post #10](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/improve-excel-accuracy-over-15-digits.3877354/), you can use a custom function:

```
Function Times(ParamArray v())

    Dim j As Long
    Times = CDec(1)

    For j = 0 To UBound(v)
        Times = Times * v(j)
    Next j

    If WorksheetFunction.Log10(Times) > 15 Then
        Times = FormatNumber(Times, , , vbTrue)
    End If

End Function
```

This way you can have the correct outcome.

[image]